# Когда разместился, а когда поместился

Tags: выбор-слов

Всюду говорят: «Постоялец разместился в номере», «Человек разместился на стуле». Но ведь это ошибки, да?

Как я вижу: можно положить и разложить. «По-» — в одно место, «раз-» во множество. Аналогично и с размещением/помещением. Или нет? Ну не способен человек размешаться в кресле. Он в него только помещается, а лучше — садится.

А вот текст вполне себе размешается, ведь он не один, а набор слов и строчек, которые действительно распределяют на макетах и веб-страницах.

С другой стороны, я подозреваю, что допустимо употребление «разместился на диване»: эта мебель — с несколькими местами, так что если прилечь, ты вполне себе размещаешься, поскольку занимаешь два или три условных «посадочных места».

Answer (score 2):

> > Всюду говорят: «Постоялец разместился в номере», «Человек разместился на стуле». Но ведь это ошибки, да?

Нет, не ошибки. "Поместился" означало бы, что постояльцу хватило места в номере, а человеку – на стуле. А разместился – значит устроился.

Comment: Какова тогда, по-вашему, роль приставки "раз-"? Её значение? По справочникам, она указывает на 1) Разъединение (разрезать) 2) Высшую степень качества (разудалый) 3) Аннулирование (разморозить) 4) Увеличение интенсивности (раздраконить). Мои рассуждения в эту формулу укладываются. А Вашу версию чем подтвердить?

Comment: А не надо никаких "формул". Слово обладает таким замечательным свойством, как *идиоматичность*. То есть, грубо говоря, слово означает то, что оно означает, и, чтобы узнать его значение, не надо его делить на морфемы, а надо смотреть в толковый словарь. Смотрели в словарь?

Comment: Смотрел Ожегова. У него: занять местА. У Даля: "Все ли разместились?" А тем значением, про которое Вы говорите, обладает другое слово -- "приместиться". В противном случае, просто объясните, почему "разместиться" и "разгнездиться" должны выражать разный характер действий. А идиоматичность идиоматичности рознь. "Одень шапку" - чем Вам не укрепляющаяся идиома? Но это же не значит, что так правильно.

Comment: "Одень шапку" - вполне возможно, что скоро станет допустимым разговорным. А слова "приместиться" не существует. Есть "примоститься". На стуле примоститься можно, в номере - нельзя. И "разгнездиться" тоже не существует. **"В противном случае, просто объясните..."** -- Еще раз: слово означает то, что означает.

Comment: Меня бы устроила ссылка на авторитетный источник. Рассуждения в духе "слово есть" и "слово означает" не убедительны. Где написано, что оно означает именно сеть в кресло, например.

Comment: Толковые словари не авторитет? Тогда печалька...

Comment: Печалька, что Вы ни ссылки, ни цитаты не дали. Абстрактные "словари" не авторитет.

Comment: Никакие не абстрактные. Выбирайте: Ожегов, Кузнецов, Ефремова... Я же вам не собес, верно? Вам нужно – вы и ищите. Только сначала перечитайте свой вопрос и ищите именно те слова, которые вы сочли "ошибками".

Comment: Вот из Ожегова: "РАЗМЕСТИТЬСЯ, -ещусь, -естйшься; сое. Занять места; поместиться. Пассажиры разместились в вагоне. Библиотека разместилась на первом этаже". Как это подтверждает Вашу версию?  Даёте ответ, можно найти время, чтобы его чем-то обосновывать, я считаю.

Comment: Во, отличный пример. Пассажиры разместились в вагоне, а ваш постоялец разместился в номере. Нет, можно, конечно, поупираться, поупрямиться (это, мол, не то), но это именно одно и то же.

Comment: Я бы не задал этот вопрос, если бы всё было так очевидно. Судите сами: пассажиров много. Разместились они по многу мест. Про номер говорить не стану (да, изначально говорил о нём, но теперь не стану). Это уже профессиональная терминология. Не обязательно она опирается на грамматику. Сведу вопрос к: можно ли разместиться одному человеку на одном месте. Скажем, на кресле. Если да, какой словарь или правило на это указывают.

Comment: Эх... Признаю, я чувак порой несдержанный, а вы вроде как исповедуете строгую логику. Но у вас не логика, у вас, пардон, занудство. Это не одно и то же. Да, ответ на последний вопрос: можно. Можно разместиться человеку на одном месте. Тот же Ожегов указывает, перечитайте: *занять места; поместиться*. А главное - так действительно говорят. Зайдите в Нацкорпус, что ли...

Comment: Ну так места же  (мн. число)  у Ожегова. Я ж не с потолка это взял. Всё верно -- я за логику. Напишет, скажем, Розенталь, что кто-то один разместился на слуле/кресле/табуретке, вопрос будет снят. А что говорят в жизни и пишут в нацкорпусе -- это архив противоречий. Например, в теме "кой" или "коий" нацкорпус дал одинаковое количество для обоих вариантов.

Comment: *А что говорят в жизни и пишут в нацкорпусе -- это архив противоречий* - Ну извините. Язык не подчиняется такой логике, которую исповедуете вы.

Comment: Моя логика проста: если в словаре зафиксировано такое значение (разместиться на стуле), то это языковая норма. А если нет, но так только кто-то пишет и говорит, то извините. Мой вопрос о правиле. Я сразу привёл причины своих сомнений на основании приставок. Я объяснил, что "отдельная терминология" для меня сомнительный авторитет. Но я без вопросов приму ответ со ссылкой на словарь, где такое значение зафиксировано, -- один человек разместился на одном месте.

Comment: Моя логика проста: если в словаре зафиксировано такое значение (разместиться на стуле), то это языковая норма. А если нет, но так только кто-то пишет и говорит, то извините. Мой вопрос о правиле. Я сразу привёл причины своих сомнений на основании приставок. Я объяснил, что "отельная терминология" для меня сомнительный авторитет. Но я без вопросов приму ответ со ссылкой на словарь, где такое значение зафиксировано, -- один человек разместился на одном месте.

Comment: Видите ли, тогда словари стали бы на порядок толще, чем они есть, а они и сейчас достаточно толстые. Древние говорили: умный поймет. *"...для меня сомнительный авторитет"* -- ради бога. Выходит, везде это слово употребляется ошибочно. Приоритет этого "открытия" целиком за вами.